# Undefined function the_field in Visual Studio Code

Tags: php, wordpress, visual-studio-code

I'm trying to display the data of a ACF but I'm getting this error in Visual Studio Code:

[image]

This is the entire code. I tried reinstalling the plugin, added PHP to the path but nothing seems to be working.

```
Single.php
<?php get_header();?>

    <div class="container">

        <div class="row">
            <div>

            <img src="<?php the_post_thumbnail_url('thumbnail'); ?>" id="single_header">


                        <div id="single_content">
                            <?php if (have_posts()):while (have_posts()):the_post(); ?>
                                <?php 
                                    $fn=get_the_author_meta('first_name');
                                    $lname=get_the_author_meta('last_name');
                                    $email=get_the_author_meta('email');
                                ?>

                                    <h1 class="text=cenetr nt-3 mb-5 text-primary"><?php the_title();?></h1>
                                    <small>Publishor:<?php echo $fn; ?></small>

                                        <p><?php the_content();?></p>

                                    <?php
                                            endwhile;
                                        endif;

                                    ?>

                                    <?php previous_post_link(); ?>
                                    <?php next_post_link(); ?>
                        </div>

                        <div id="single_extraInfo"> 
                            <p>Company: <?php the_field('flight_company'); ?></p>
                            <p>Date: <?php the_field('flight_date'); ?></p>
                            <p>Capacity: <?php the_field('flight_capacity'); ?></p>

                        </div>
            </div>


    
        </div>
    </div>

    <?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: The PHP extension `intelephense` you are using in VSCode does not know anything about that function.

Comment: so how can i fix that

Comment: search the inteliphense site/git repo, they normally seems to have leat breaking fixes hanging about in there

Comment: it does not stop the code working by the way, its just the checker reporting

Comment: i cant find any, can u give me a lin or something

Answer (score 9):

On top of what @DaleNguyen adviced above...

Make sure the directory that contains **acf plugin** is in your **Vs Code**. Example, instead of only opening the **theme** directory in Vs Code in which you are probably working, open the entire **wp_content** directory in your VS Code. That way, when intelephence run in the back-ground, it will be able to reach the **plugins** folder and **acf functions** in the **acf plugin folder**.

Comment: This solved it for me. I had ```undefined type WC_Payment_Gateway``` but when I included the whole ```wp_content``` directory (```File > Open Folder > C:\wamp64\www\WORDPRESSINSTALLATION\wp-content```) as you said the error went away.

Answer (score 5):

In the `intelephense`, make sure you add `wordpress` to the list.

[image]

Comment: it is but the error still shows, the code is working though so its all good, thanks

Comment: the_field() is not a wordpress function, but an AdvancedCustomFields plugin function so adding 'wordpress' does not have an effect sadly, but should be added for sure anyway if you are using ACF as you no doubt using other WordPress functions in the same project

Answer (score 1):

Make sure to open the entire wp_content directory in your VS Code.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35166987)

Answer (score 0):

@james-serengia answered with one working solution that the ACF plugin folder should be open in the same workspace as the code you are working on and the warning disappears.

Alternatively if that is inconvenient, you can add you can add the ACF stubs to VSCode. It is a bit of messing around but when it is done, it is done. [See this explanation](https://github.com/bmewburn/vscode-intelephense/issues/1726#issuecomment-1075377620).